# Add view on UIScrollView without it scrolling (programatically)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am trying to add a Page Control on top of my UIScrollView Custom class. Everything is wokring fine. But whenever I slide the scrollView, the Page Control will slide along the first Image as well.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftyGif

class MBSPagingScrollView: UIScrollView {

var pageControl = UIPageControl()
var imagesArray = [String]()

override init (frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)
}

convenience init () {
    self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
}

init(frame : CGRect, imagesarray : [String]){
    super.init(frame : frame)

    imagesArray = imagesarray

    self.isPagingEnabled = true
    self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

    for (index, imageName) in imagesArray.enumerated() {

        var imageView = UIImageView()

        if imageName.hasSuffix(".gif") {
            let gifManager = SwiftyGifManager(memoryLimit:30)
            let gif = UIImage(gifName: imageName)
            imageView = UIImageView(gifImage: gif, manager: gifManager)
        }

        else {
            imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageName))
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
        }

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(index) * self.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        self.addSubview(imageView)

    }

    self.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.frame.size.width * CGFloat(imagesArray.count),height: self.frame.size.height)

    configurePageControl()
    pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.changePage(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}

func configurePageControl() {
    self.pageControl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - 50, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 50)
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = imagesArray.count
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = MainOrangeColor
    self.addSubview(pageControl)
}

//    // MARK : TO CHANGE WHILE CLICKING ON PAGE CONTROL
    func changePage(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
        let x = CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage) * self.frame.size.width
        self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:x, y:0), animated: true)
    }

func selfDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = round(self.contentOffset.x / self.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

}

And here are images of the problem happening

[image: Page control is centered on the first image]

[image]

As you can see the Page Control is sliding with the first image. I need it to stay in the center.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do that by going to Storyboard, and from the left menu of the UI Builder, drag your page control down and put it out of your scroll view and under it, like in the following picture:

[image]

Then you'll need to add the suitable constraints to place your page control properly.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello, But I am coding this programmatically without story board. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani that’s irrelevant. The idea is the same whether it’s in a storyboard, nib or code. Just add the page control to the view. Not the scroll view.

Comment: You are welcome Mohamed. I'm sorry this didn't help you.. I think the problem may be related to that you're adding your page control to your scroll view while it should be floating on it instead.
For example, you can put `configurePageControl ` method in your view controller and do the configuration of your page control inside the view controller and add the page control to `self.view`.

Comment: @Fogmeister my class if UIScrollView, it does not contain a view that's the point

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want it to scroll... don’t add it to the **scroll** View.

Just add the page control to the `self.view` instead of to the scroll view.

Comment: But this is a custom class of type UIScrollView

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani why? What are you gaining by making a subclass? Sounds to me more like you should be using a UIScrollView and not subclassing it at all.

Comment: I want to make  UIScrollView with pagination without using UIPageViewController (I need it as a scrollview not a view controller)

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani or make a subclass called `ImagesViewController` and make it a subclass of UIViewController. Then add its view in the place where you want it. A scroll view shouldn’t be concerned with how many pages it has.

Comment: Is it recommended to use viewcontroller as a subview inside another view controller?

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani you want to... but why? What functionality are you adding to UIScrollView? None. You are subclassing where you should be setting properties. Don’t subclass in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152302/discussion-between-mohammad-bashir-sidani-and-fogmeister).

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani definitely. It allows you to put the logic in the correct place. Nice way of keeping complex logic in a reusable component.